# What should I do after a low-voltage wire was cut putting the furnace door back on?

Tags: hvac, furnace, low-voltage

I have the basic Honeywell thermostat that a lot of people have. All the thermostat wires go to the blower in the attic (for the central air). They are spliced with wires that then go to the furnace.

Everything going was fine until Saturday, when the AC wouldn't work. That's a different issue. While looking in the furnace, and replacing the door, the white wire was cut by the metal door. I bypassed that cut by splicing the wires, but the furnace still won't kick on.

What should I do to troubleshoot and repair it?

Comment: If you're luck you blew a fuse, or damaged another wire.   If you're unlucky, you blew the transformer.  Does the system work in cooling mode, or with the fan set to ON? Do you have a multimeter or voltmeter, and the ability to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Shorting one of the thermostat wires to ground might have tripped the breaker on the 24 VAC transformer that powers the thermostat.

Another option is that you damaged multiple wires but only the white one badly enough to notice it.